# SUBSTRING_INDEX with GROUP_CONCAT in codeigniter not working

Tags: mysql, sql, codeigniter

public function getProductsById($id)
    {

```
    $this->db->select('product.*,SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(product_properties.name), " ", 4) as pname');       
    $this->db->from('product');        
    $this->db->where('product.subcategory_id',$id);                
    $this->db->join('product_properties','product_properties.product_id=product.id');
    $this->db->group_by('product_properties.product_id');
    return @$this->db->get()->result_array();
}
```

[This is the error i see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jm0xf.png)

Please help!

Comment: Try to escape the double quotes `\"`

Comment: Replace single quotes by double quotes and double quotes to single:

$this->db->select("product.*,SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(product_properties.name), ' ', 4) as pname");